# Can we obtain $f(y+x)=y+f(x)$ from $f(x^2+f(x)^2+x)=f(x)^2+x^2+f(x)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> $\mathbb Z^+$ is the set of positive integers. Find all functions $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that
>   $$f(m^2+f(n))=f(m)^2+n\quad(\clubsuit)$$

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion: $f(x^2+f(y))=f(x)^2+y \; \forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$
$P(x,x)$ gives us $f(x^2+f(x))=f(x)^2+x$.
$P(x,x^2+f(x))$ gives us $f(x^2+f(x)^2+x)=f(x)^2+x^2+f(x)$.

Can we obtain $f(y+x)=y+f(x)$ from $f(x^2+f(x)^2+x)=f(x)^2+x^2+f(x)$ ?

Comment: The last relation is true at least for $y \in \{ x^2 + f(x)^2 : x \in \Bbb{Z}^+ \}$, but is unclear if it extends to other values of $y$ as well. In particular, sum of squares cannot cover all the positive integers.

Comment: FYI: If we replace $\mathbb{Z}_+$ with $\mathbb{R}$ then this is an old IMO problem ([IMO 92 Problem 2](http://abelkonkurransen.no/problems/imo_92_prob_en.pdf), solution [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln922.html)).

Answer (score 6):

> Notations and assumptions

1. $\circ$ denotes composition.
2. $g:= f\circ f\quad(\diamondsuit)$

> **Theorem$(\heartsuit)$:**$\qquad g(n)=n\quad\forall\; n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$

For arbitrary $m,n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ we have
$$\begin{align}
 &\quad \color{#F0A}{g(n)^2+m^2+f(1)}\\
\stackrel{\diamondsuit,\clubsuit}=&\quad f(\color{red}{f(n)^2}+\color{blue}{f(m^2+f(1))})\\
\stackrel{\clubsuit}=&\quad f(\color{red}{f(n)^2}+\color{blue}{f(m)^2+1})\\
=&\quad f(\color{blue}{f(m)^2}+\color{red}{f(n)^2+1})\\
\stackrel{\clubsuit}=&\quad f(\color{blue}{f(m)^2}+\color{red}{f(n^2+f(1))})\\
\stackrel{\diamondsuit,\clubsuit}=&\quad \color{#F0A}{g(m)^2+n^2+f(1)}\\
\therefore&\quad g(n)^2-n^2=g(m)^2-m^2
\end{align}$$
Note that $g(n)$ is positive and can't be $-n$. So the following are true.

$g(n)= n$ for **some** $n\iff g(n)= n$ for **all** $n$.

$g(n)\neq n$ for **some** $n\iff g(n)\neq n$ for **all** $n$.

Assuming $g(n)\neq n$ and remembering $g(n)\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ we see
$$\therefore\quad\underbrace{\color{purple}{|g(n)+n|}}_{>n}\underbrace{|g(n)-n|}_{\ge1}=|g(1)^2-1^2|
$$

i.e. RHS is a constant integer but LHS can be arbitrarily large which is absurd. Therefore $g(n)=n$.

> **Theorem$(\spadesuit)$:**$\qquad f$ is strictly increasing

$$
f(\color{red}{n}+\color{blue}{1})\stackrel{\heartsuit}=f(\color{blue}{1^2}+\color{red}{g(n)})\stackrel{\diamondsuit,\clubsuit}=f(1)^2+f(n)\stackrel{}>f(n)
$$

> **Conclusion:**$\qquad f(n)=n$

$n>f(n)$ yields a contradiction:
$$
\color{red}{n}>\color{blue}{f(n)}\stackrel{\spadesuit}\iff f(\color{red}n)>f(\color{blue}{f(n)})\stackrel{\diamondsuit}\iff
f(n)>g(n)\stackrel{\heartsuit}\iff f(n)>n
$$ 
Similarly, $n<f(n)$ yields a contradiction:
$$
\color{red}{n}<\color{blue}{f(n)}\stackrel{\spadesuit}\iff f(\color{red}n)<f(\color{blue}{f(n)})\stackrel{\diamondsuit}\iff
f(n)<g(n)\stackrel{\heartsuit}\iff f(n)<n
$$ 
Therefore we conclude:
$$ f(n)=n$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an incomplete idea to actually solve the quoted problem (as opposed to your specific question about $f(x+y)=y+f(x)$). This idea might go nowhere. Define $a$ to be $f(1)$. It's easy to show using induction that if $a=1$, then $f$ is the identity function.

If $a=2$, we can arrive at a contradiction:

$$
\begin{align}
f(1^2+f(1))&=f(1)^2+1\\
f(1+2)&=4+1\\
f(3)&=5\\
\implies f(1^2+f(3))&=f(1)^2+3\\
f(1+5)&=4+3\\
f(6)&=7\\
\implies f(1^2+f(6))&=f(1)^2+6\\
f(1+7)&=4+6\\
f(8)&=10\\
\implies f(1^2+f(8))&=f(1)^2+8\\
f(1+10)&=4+8\\
f(11)&=12
\end{align}
$$

But 
$$
\begin{align}
f(3^2+f(1))&=f(3)^2+1\\
f(9+2)&=25+1\\
f(11)&=26
\end{align}
$$

This contradiction rules out $f(1)$ being $2$. Perhaps you can find a pattern to generalize and show that $f(1)$ must be $1$, which would prove that $f$ must be the identity. (I had no luck finding such a pattern though.)

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \wedge f(m^2 + f(n)) = f(m)^2 + n.
$$
For a fixed $m$ and $n=x$ we get
$$
f(m^2 + f(x)) = f(m)^2 + x.
$$
In general we can write
$$
f(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k.
$$
Whence
$$
f'(m^2 + f(x)) f'(x) = 1.
$$
Thus $f'(x) = 1$.
So we obtain
$$
f(x) = a + x.
$$
Putting it back we get
$$
a + [ m^2 + a + n ] = a^2 + 2 a m + m^2 + n \Rightarrow 2a = a^2 + 2 a m.
$$
Whence
$$
a = 0.
$$
So the general solutions is
$$
f(x) = x.
$$