# $x^2-x+1$ has a root $\!\bmod p\,$ for infinitely many primes $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, solution-verification

Prove that the equation $$x^2 - x + 1 = p(x+y)$$ has integral solutions for infinitely many primes $p$.

First, we prove that there is a solution for at least one prime, $p$. Now, $x(x-1) + 1$ is always odd so there is no solution for $p=2$. We prove there is a solution for $p=3$. If $p=3$, $y = (x-2)^2/3-1$. We get integral solutions whenever we get $x = 3m +2$, where $m$ is any integer.$\\$
We provide a proof by contradiction which is   similar to Euclid's proof of there being infinitely many primes. \Let us assume that it is is true for only finitely many primes, and name the largest prime for which the equation is true $P$.\\We set $$x = 2\cdot3\cdot5\dots P$$ $x$ is the product of all primes upto $P.\\$
Then, the term $x(x-1) + 1$ is either prime or composite. If it is prime, then we set $p = x(x-1) + 1, y = 1 - x$ and get a solution. If it is composite, we write $x(x-1) + 1 = p\times q$, where $p$ is any prime factor of $x(x-1)+1$, and $q$ is an integer, $q = (x(x-1)+1)/p$. Now, $x(x-1) + 1$ is not divisible by any prime upto $P$ since it leaves a remainder of $1$ with all of them. So, $p > P$. We set $y=q-x$ for a solution.$\\$In either case, we get a solution for a prime $p > P$, which means there's no largest prime for which this equation has solutions. This contradicts the assumption that there are solutions for only finitely many primes.

I feel like I'm missing some step. Is this correct ?

Comment: What you've proved is _if there are solutions for only finitely many primes, $x=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots P$ is not a solution_. I don't understand how you can conclude _solution exists for infinitely many primes_ from that.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife I haven't concluded it. I was trying to use a similar argument as Euclid did. If I succeed in showing that there is always a solution for such an $x$, then it will show that it's not possible for there to be only finitely many solutions.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife Please check my proof now. I have made modifications.

Comment: If $p=2$, then there are no solutions, because it's impossible to have $2\mid x^2-x+1$, because $x(x-1)+1$ is always odd, because $x(x-1)$ is a product of two consecutive integers.

Comment: @user236182 Neat observation. I have managed to prove that if there is a solution for even one prime, then there are solutions for infinitely many primes. Help me prove that there is a solution for at least one prime.

Comment: $(3 m-1)^2-(3 m-1)+1-3 (3 m-1+3 m^2)=6-18m$ never equals $0$

Comment: @user236182 Your feedback has been taken.

Comment: @user230452 Your proof as it currently stands, is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B13) (QR).

$$x^2 - x + 1 = p(x+y)$$

$$\iff x^2-x+1-px=py$$

for a fixed $x\in\mathbb Z$ and prime $p$ has a solution $y\in\mathbb Z$ if and only if $p\mid x^2-x+1-px$, i.e. if and only if $p\mid x^2-x+1$.

Your problem is equivalent to proving that $p\mid x^2-x+1$ has a solution $x\in\mathbb Z$ for infinitely many primes $p$.

Let $p\ge 5$. $$\exists x\in\mathbb Z\left(x^2-x+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}\right)$$

$$\stackrel{\cdot 4}\iff \exists x\in\mathbb Z\left((2x-1)^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}\right)$$

$$\stackrel{(*)}\iff \left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1$$

$$\stackrel{(\text{QR})}\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$

$(*)$: I'll explain a few things. Firstly, I'm using the [Legendre Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Secondly, the equivalence holds because if $t^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$ for some $t\in\mathbb Z$ (i.e. if $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$), then the congruence $t\equiv 2x-1\pmod{p}$ has the solution $x\equiv 2^{-1}(t+1)\pmod{p}$.

Therefore your equation has a solution $(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2$ if and only if either $p=3$ or $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ ($p=3$ gives a solution $(x,y)=(2,-1)$ and you can find that $p=2$ gives no solutions, because $x^2-x=x(x-1)$ is always even).

There are infinitely many primes $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. It follows from the more general [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) or from a simpler proof that only uses QR, e.g. the one given in the last page of [this paper](http://www2.math.ethz.ch/u/felder/Teaching/WS200405/Proseminar/Problem4).

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity is a bit of a heavyweight issue. Do you have a more elementary solution ? And, by the way, nice meeting you. I don't think I've met anybody who shares the first 6 letters of my username before !

Comment: I read this problem in a journal called Crux Mathematicorum. I recorded the problem but not the solution or the reference to the exact issue. When I tried to solve it today, I got stuck trying to complete what I remembered of the proof.

Comment: Please check my proof and tell me if its right or wrong.

Comment: @user230452 It's an incorrect proof, like the first commenter said, and he explained it well. Again, you're trying to use a proof by contradiction. What you've proved exactly is that if there are finitely many primes with integer solutions, then, if $P$ is the largest such prime, $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots P$ is not a solution. This doesn't give a contradiction. There's no reason that $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots P$ should be a solution. There exist integer solutions, but one of them doesn't have to be with $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots P$.

Comment: I meant to say that if $x = 2\cdot3\cdot5 \dots P$, then $p$ would be greater than $P$. It contradicts the assumption that there is a largest prime for which the equation has solutions. This particular choice of $x$ proves not just that it doesn't have any solution for $p<P$, but any solution it does have involves $p >P$. I have also provided reasons why it should have a solution. $LHS$ has to be either prime or composite. In either case, there's an integral value of $y$ possible.

Comment: @user230452 You say "if $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots P$, then $p$ would be greater than $P$". This proves that $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots P$ is not a solution. And there's no reason that it should be, so we get no contradiction. Even if the equation should have a solution (i.e. be solvable), there's no given reason why one of the solutions should be the specific choice $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots P$.

Comment: I have expressed myself more clearly and rewritten the proof.

Comment: @user236182 I've posted a proof which I don't think uses quadratic reciprocity (implicitly or explicitly) :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, your proof is beyond my current level. I'll come back and read this in a couple of months.

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes easily generalizes to show that infinitely many primes divide values of $\,f(x) = x^2 -x + 1.\,$ First $\,3\mid f(2).\,$ Given primes $\,3,p_2,\ldots\,p_k\,$ that divide values of $\,f,\,$ let $\,k\,$ be their product. $\,f(k)\,$ is coprime to $\,k\,$ since $\ {\rm mod}\ k\!:\ f(k) \equiv f(0)\equiv 1.\,$ Thus choosing any prime factor of $\,f(k)\,$ yields a new prime divisor (note $\,k>1\,$ $\Rightarrow\,$ $\,f(k)>1\,$ so $\,f(k)\,$ does have a prime factor).

Clearly the same type of argument works for any polynomial $\,f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ with $\,f(0) = \pm1$.

Answer (score 1):

> Assumptions

$$0\notin\mathbb N\\n\in\mathbb N$$

> $x^2-x+1$ is composite for infinitely many $x\in\mathbb N$

Proof: 
$$
x=3n+2\implies x^2-x+1=\color{red}{3}\times(3n^2+3n+1)
$$

> There are infinitely many primes that can divide natural numbers of form $x^2-x+1$.

Proof: Suppose our claim is not true and in fact $q_1=\color{red}{3},q_2,\cdots,q_k$ are the only primes that can divide a natural number of form $x^2-x+1$. Borrowing Euclid's argument let $$n=\prod_{j=1}^kq_j\\ x=3n+2$$
Therefore, $x^2-x+1$ is not a prime and
$$
x^2-x+1\equiv3\not\equiv0\mod q_j\;\forall j\neq1\\
\implies q_j\not| x^2-x+1\;\forall j\neq1
$$
Therefore our assumption and [the fundamental theorem of arithmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Applications) indicate, for some $q\in\mathbb N$
$$\begin{align}
&x^2-x-1=\color{red}{3}^q \\
\implies& 3n^2+3n+1=3^{q-1}\\
\implies& 1\equiv 3^{q-1}\mod 3\\
\implies& q=1\\
\implies& x^2-x+1=3
\end{align}
$$
which contradicts
$$
x^2-x+1>(x-1)^2=(3n+1)^2\ge(3q_1+1)^2=100
$$

> Solution to the current problem

Suppose $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_m$ are the only primes for which integral solution exists. Using the above lemma we can find a prime $p$ not in this list such that $p| x^2-x+1$ for some $x\in\mathbb N$. Set 
$$
y={x^2-x+1\over p}-x
$$
which is definitely an integer (but not necessarily a natural number). Thus we have found a new prime $p$ for which an integral solution to the given equation exists. Therefore, our assumption that the given equation has integral solutions for finitely many choices of $p$ can't be true.

Comment: Nice one. By the way, nice presentation. Is there any book that you read that taught you to present proofs like this ? I want to improve my presentation, but if I write so much for each proof, I might not be able to do a lot of problems.

Comment: @user230452 Unfortunately I've never taken a course in number theory or finished a considerable part of a number theory book. I just read a lot of proofs online :)

Comment: Me too. I'm self studying all this. I'm not even in a Mathematics course, unfortunately. I like collecting solutions of elegant problems, and most of my proofs look like what I wrote in the question. I'd like them to be better but I think if I wrote this much, I wouldn't finish much. Did you take some course which improved your proof writing skills ?

Comment: Do you think it's worth it for me to learn real analysis ? I would but I find real analysis books kind of boring. Especially, the beginning. And, if so, which book did you use ?

Comment: @user230452 I forgot to mention Terry Tao's book _problem solving: a personal perspective_. I think I picked up this form of proof presentation from there.[This is one of my best answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350094/can-we-obtain-fyx-yfx-from-fx2fx2x-fx2x2fx/1351089#1351089) and it certainly uses Tao's advice: to prove lots of  easy little facts concerning the problem and list them. If you combine lot of little facts, you get a __big__ one. I would advise against signing up for a real-analysis course but it's definitely worthwhile to check out the beginner level books :)

Comment: I don't have the option of signing up for a course anyway because there's nothing like that in college.. I have to learn from books, which I prefer in any case. I don't like learning in classes, with lectures and tests and stuff and prefer self learning through books rather than videos.

Comment: @user230452 You're correct, in hands of the wrong professor ( where I live, most of them are _wrong_), lectures are boring as fudge :(

Comment: I agree with you. However, are there any mistakes in my proof, as it is now ?

Comment: Are you an undergraduate student ? Nice talking to you. I hope I see you around more.