# Show that there are infinitely many $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a!+(a+2)!$ divides $(a+2\lfloor{\sqrt{a}}\rfloor)!$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, factorial

The question is:

> Show that there are infinitely many natural number $a$ such that $a!+(a+2)!$ divides $(a+2\lfloor{\sqrt{a}\rfloor})!$.

**My attempt:**
I let $a=(b-1)^2$ for a natural number $b>1$. Then $a!+(a+2)!$ becomes
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(b-1)^2!+((b-1)^2+2)!&=(b-1)^2!\left(1+((b-1)^2+2)((b-1)^2+1)\right),\\
&=(b-1)^2!\left(1+(b^2-2b+3)(b^2-2b+2)\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Then $(a+2\lfloor\sqrt{a}\rfloor)!$ becomes
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left((b-1)^2+2\left\lfloor\sqrt{(b-1)^2}\right\rfloor\right)!&=\left((b-1)^2+2(b-1)\right)!,\\
&=(b^2-1)!,\\
&=(b^2-1)(b^2-2)\dots\left(b^2-(2b-1)\right)!
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
So then I'm left with proving that $\left(1+(b^2-2b+3)(b^2-2b+2)\right)$ divides $(b^2-1)(b^2-2)\dots(b^2-(2b-2)).$ However, a quick checking for $b=3$ gives me $31\nmid8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$, and now I'm stumped.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is the same as $(a^2+3a+3)|\prod_{k=1}^{2\lfloor{\sqrt{a}\rfloor}}(a+k)
$, so we need to find a set of $a$s such that the left side factors nicely. Haven't been able to do this.

Comment: Replace $a$ by $a-1$ so that you get $a^2+a+1$ instead of $a^2+3a+3$. And now recall that $x^4+x^2+1$ has a nice factorisation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right general idea. However, rather than your $a=(b-1)^2$, which I also wasn't able to finish with, the following uses $a=b^2-1$ instead. First, we have

$$a! + (a+2)! = a! + a!(a+1)(a+2) = a!(1 + (a+1)(a+2)) = a!(a^2 + 3a + 3) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$(a+2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor)! = a!(a+1)(a+2)\ldots(a+2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor) = a!\prod_{k=1}^{2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor}(a+k) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus, since $a! \neq 0$, the divisibility condition becomes

$$a!(a^2 + 3a + 3) \mid a!\prod_{j=1}^{2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor}(a+j) \;\;\to\;\; (a^2 + 3a + 3)\mid \prod_{j=1}^{2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor}(a+j) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

as [marty cohen's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757761/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-a-in-mathbbn-such-that-aa2-divid#comment10099691_4757761) indicates.

Next, consider we have for some positive integer $j$ that
$$a + j \mid a^2 + 3a + 3 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Letting $a + j = k \;\to\; a \equiv -j \pmod{k}$, then from \eqref{eq4A} we have, for some positive integer $m$, that

$$a^2 + 3a + 3 \equiv (-j)^2 + 3(-j) + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{k} \;\;\to\;\; j^2 - 3j + 3 = mk \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

With $m = 1$, we get

$$j^2 - 3j + 3 = a + j \;\;\to\;\; a = j^2 - 4j + 3 = (j - 2)^2 - 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Letting $b = j - 2$, then

$$a = b^2 - 1 \;\;\to\;\; 2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor = 2(b-1) = 2b - 2 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

and

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a^2 + 3a + 3 & = (b^2-1)^2 + 3(b^2 - 1) + 3 \\
& = b^4 - 2b^2 + 1 + 3b^2 - 3 + 3 \\
& = b^4 + b^2 + 1 \\
& = (b^2 + b + 1)(b^2 - b + 1) \\
& = ((b^2 - 1) + b + 2)((b^2 - 1) - b + 2) \\
& = (a + b + 2)(a - b + 2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

For $b \ge 4$, we have $b + 2 \le 2b - 2$, so $a + b + 2$ is a factor of $\prod_{j=1}^{2\lfloor \sqrt{a}\rfloor}(a+j)$ (with $j=b+2$ in \eqref{eq4A} also indicating this). As for the $b^2 - b + 1$ factor, note this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1853898) of [$x^2-x+1$ has a root $\!\bmod p\,$ for infinitely many primes $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1853846) proves that, for *every* prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, there's a positive integer value of $b$ where $p \mid b^2 - b + 1$. As that answer shows, this comes from $(2b-1)^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$. Let $b_0$ be a solution of this with $1 \lt b_0 \lt p-1$. Since $2b_0-1\not\equiv 0,\pm 1\pmod{p}$, then if $2b_0 - 1 \gt p + 1$, choose $b=b_0$ since we have $2b - 2 \gt p$. Otherwise, $2b_0 - 1 \lt p - 1 \;\to\; -(2b_0 - 1) \gt -p + 1 \;\to\; 2p - (2b_0 - 1) \gt p + 1$, so $2(p-b_0+1)- 2 \gt p$. Since $(2p - (2b_0 - 1))^2\equiv(2b_0 - 1)^2\equiv-3\pmod{p}$ is also a solution, we can choose $b = p-b_0+1$ (where $1 \lt b \lt p - 1$ is also true) in this case.

Note that, in both cases, we have $p \mid b^2 - b + 1$, so $\frac{b^2 - b + 1}{p}$ is an integer. Also, with $b^2 - b + 1 \lt b^2$ and $b \lt p \;\to\; b^2 \lt p^2$, we have $\frac{b^2 - b + 1}{p} \lt p \lt 2b - 2$. Thus, since for all positive integers $n$, the product of any at least $n$ consecutive integers always has at least one factor of $n$, there exists $1 \le j_1,j_2 \le 2\lfloor\sqrt{a}\rfloor - 1$ (note we can reduce this upper value by $1$) where $p \mid a + j_1$ and $\frac{b^2 - b + 1}{p} \mid a + j_2$.

The only thing left to consider is if there is any overlap of a factor $\gt 1$ between $b^2 + b + 1$ and $b^2 - b + 1$. However, any such factor must divide $(b^2 + b + 1) - (b^2 - b + 1) = 2b$, but $b^2 \pm b + 1$ are odd and $\gcd(b, b^2 \pm b + 1) = 1$.

This shows that, for each of the infinitely many primes where $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ (e.g., from [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), as indicated in the previously linked answer), there's a corresponding $a$ where \eqref{eq3A} is true (e.g., for $p=7$, we have $b=5$ and $a=24$ works).